# Как запустить программу в фоне через вызов exec.Command?

Tags: linux, golang

Реализовал приложение, которое принимает данные на порту по протоколу UDP. Когда запускаю данное приложение, из консоли оно работает как надо.

Далее, написал к нему API для выключения, включения и перезапуска. Добавил его в переменную `$PATH`, при первом POST-запросе оно запускается, но данные не принимает. Если пошлю запрос на выключение и потом на включение, начинает принимать данные, но только с одного клиента и только один раз. Далее нужно снова повторить операцию вкл/выкл.

Напомню, что при обычном включении не через API все работает как надо. Всё запускаю из под рута.

```golang
func start(e echo.Context) error {
    path, err := exec.LookPath(PARSERNAME)
    if err != nil {
          return err
    }
    cmd = exec.Command(path, "-p")
    err = cmd.Start()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        err = cmd.Wait()
        if err != nil {
             fmt.Printf("Err: %v\n", err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    return e.String(http.StatusOK,fmt.Sprintf("start %s\n",
        time.Now().Format("Jan _2 15:04:05")))
}


func stop(e echo.Context) error {
     if err := cmd.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
         fmt.Printf("Err: %v\n", err)
     }
     return e.String(http.StatusOK,fmt.Sprintf(" stop %s\n",
         time.Now().Format("Jan _2 15:04:05")))
}
```

Comment: У вас глобальная переменная `cmd` что ли?

Comment: @Ainar-G ну кода немного решил её вынести в глобальную

Comment: @Ainar-G  все верно.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, это потоконебезопасно.  Во-вторых, если у вас _один_ глобальный инстанс команды, как вы ожидаете выполнять _несколько_ команд?  Вам нужно всю архитектуру переработать.

Comment: @Ainar-G а зачем мне выполнять несколько команд ? если мне в конкретный момент нужно либо выключить либо включить? проблема возникает в том что при включение его через вызов api,  udp сервер не принимает данные, но если я просто включу через терминал то все работает.